# How i can solve this e-mail string problem? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, string

I have the e-mail address that came via e-mail with python, but it comes as follows. how can i solve this problem?

```
incoming format = a href3D"mailto:ahmet
ca@abc.tr"

desired format  = ahmetca@abc.tr
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable

Comment: TL;DR: you need to 1) properly parse and decode the email as such, in this case it looks like it uses quoted-printable encoding. Once you've done that, you 2) need to parse the HTML it contains to extract the `href` attribute and 3) split the `mailto:` from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try regex

```
emails = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", incoming)
print(emails)
```

will give

```
['ahmeta@abc.tr']
```

Comment: Yes, that is true but my incoming format is not like this. There is a " sign at the end.

Comment: what sign ur getting can u be specific

Comment: Can you take a look at my incoming format above? not like your example

Comment: have updated answer does it help ?

Comment: incoming  = a href3D"mailto:ahmet
                  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>>>>>> I get this error.

Comment: have u added quotes before the incoming data

Comment: I forgot to put quotation marks. now i did and the solution you wrote worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: glad to help if the answer was useful kindly accept it